# calling init() method from service method in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Can we call init() method from service() method in servlet ? I got this as an interview question. Why would anyone do this anyway ?

Comment: You can definitely call it, but god bless the team in which someone writes that kind of code. To given an analogy, Can you cut yourself with knife? Yes, but it will bleed you to death..

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? It'd only take you a couple of minutes :)

Comment: I wish there was a "Like" button here

Comment: @Kal to make things clear, I was commenting on the actual question, not your knife example :)

Comment: Well I very well know that to be honest :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No reason to call `init` from `service`, `init` is meant to be called by the container - to initialise it with configuration (as the name suggests) and to allow it to do any expensive operations it needs to do (setting up connections to database or whatever).

It may make some sense if you wanted to programmatically reconfigure your servlet to call the `init` from the servlet itself, but I struggle to see this use case.

Answer (score 1):

In typical servlet lifecycle service() method won't be called before you call init() method

Answer (score 0):

You can call init as a method , not as you want it should be called in a lifecycle of servlet .

even the service method will be called only after init.

Answer (score 0):

`init()` method is called to initialize all the needed things before the servlet can be put to work.

The question asked in the interview was meant to make your knowledge knowable to them in the following fields:

1. What is `init()`
2. Why is it called for
3. Where do we call it
4. What will happen if we called it from the service

Number 4. It's like to construct a building and then to call for the buyers to settle in it and then begin putting its structure. They were asking this to know your managing and organizational talents over project handling.

In other words, doing that is to no avail, and your servlet will not be effected!

Comment: It's like to construct a building and then to call for the buyers to settle in it and then begin putting its structure. They were asking this to know your managing and organizational talents over project handling.

Answer (score 0):

The init method is designed to be called only once. It is called when the servlet is first created, and not called again for each user request. So, it is used for one-time initializations, just as with the init method of applets.

The servlet is normally created when a user first invokes a URL corresponding to the servlet, but you can also specify that the servlet be loaded when the server is first started.

When a user invokes a servlet, a single instance of each servlet gets created, with each user request resulting in a new thread that is handed off to doGet or doPost as appropriate. The init() method simply creates or loads some data that will be used throughout the life of the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

No i suggest  not to call ,because init() method should be called only once to make some initializations (like Data base connection code ,this has to be called only once ,no reason to call it more than once ) where as service method will be called for every user request (with user specific request and response objects).Imagine if u make call for init from service method then init will called so many times.So it is not a good idea to call like that.